# Defining Lambda function from dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, sympy

I'm trying to define a lambda function with more than one attribute, the attributes are `sympy` symbols and are in a dictionary as following

```
my_dict = {'sym1':sym1 , 'sym2':sym2 , ......}
```

I need to define a lambda function to execute `eval()` as follwoing :

```
fn = lambda expr , **my_dict : eval(expr)
```

so that when I call it with the dictionary with numerical values `eval` can substitute them correctly as following:

```
subs_dict={'sym1':1 , 'sym2':5 , ......)
expr = #some text eqn of the syms
x = fn(expr,**subs_dict)
print(x)
```

However, when I do this, `x` is printed as function of the symbols... Why??! And what should I do?

Comment: Why does this need to be a `lambda` instead of a `def`? And why are you trying to do your own substitution and then do a Python `eval` instead of asking sympy to substitute and eval for you?

Comment: That require me to explain alot....but this is a part of large project and it need to be done like this

Comment: about the subs of sympy, its much slower compared to this

Comment: Well, you're going to need to parse the expression, walk the parse tree doing substitutions, and then turn it back into a string to pass to `eval`. You can probably use the `ast` module in the stdlib to do most of the heavy lifting, but it's still not going to be trivial. So, go read up on `ast`, start writing something, and come back here when you get stuck.

Comment: It's much slower than something that doesn't work because you haven't even written it?

Comment: Also, I don't believe there's any deep reason that would require a lot of explanation for why this needs to be a `lambda` instead of a `def`. The only possible reasons for that are (a) it needs to be used in an expression rather than a statement, and `b` there's no good name for it. Clearly neither one is true, because you're trying to use it in an assignment expression to give it a name.

Comment: talking about slower or not....i SURE of what i say...try subs using a symbolic expr. and a same string expr. trhough eval and measure the time.....huge differece

Comment: Have you looked into `lambdify` provided by sympy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` already does what you want:

```
>>> eval("3*x**2 + 4*y", None, dict(x=0, y=-10000000))
-40000000
```

If your project does truly demand wrapping `eval` in a lambda:

```
>>> fn = lambda expr, **kwargs : eval(expr, None, kwargs)
>>> fn("3*x+4*y",x=1,y=2)
11
```

If you are using sympy, `lambdify` is a more robust alternative that comes with multiple backends:

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
>>> f = sp.lambdify((x, y), 3*x+4*y, modules='numpy')
>>> import numpy as np
>>> f(np.random.randn(10), np.random.randn(10))
array([ 3.86723102,  0.85028042, -1.74461009, -4.02824375, -0.59191871,
       -0.52022366,  5.43335779, -2.09120517, -7.16387162, -0.22421031])
```